# How to look through sheets with wildcard ? Wildcard not working

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

The following code wont work. The wildcard doesnt pick out the "rop" from the worksheet name. If the sheet name was "rop + gas + gamma", the wildcard wouldn't recognize it and the if statement would turn up false.

```
For Each ws In Worksheets

    Dim name As String

    name = "*rop*"

    If LCase(ws.name) = name Then

        sheetname = ws.name

        Exit For

    Else

next
```

Comment: Use `Like` or `InStr`. With `Like`: `If LCase(ws.name) Like name Then`

Comment: The `=` comparison operator makes the expression `True` when the expressions on either of its sides are *equal*. If the name isn't `*rop*`, then it's not equal. `=` doesn't do wildcards.